# Int? или bool?

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте!

Я встречал в определении функции или свойства следующее: `int?` или `bool?`.

Что это значит?

Спасибо.

Comment: Это значит Nullable, возвращаемый/хранимый тип может содержать не только значения описанного типа, но и Null.

Answer (score 5):

это краткая форма записи для **Nullable<int>** и **Nullable<bool>** соответственно.
типы **int** (System.Int32 точнее) и **bool** (System.Boolean) относятся к типам-значениям, а следовательно не могут содержать значение **null**. Однако иногда это бывает полезно (например при работе с базами данных, где любое значение может содержать null (если обратное не указать явно). Так вот для этого в .NET 2.0  был введен тип **Nullable<T>** (тоже кстати тип-значение), представляющий собой обертку над типами-значениями для предоставления возможности хранить **null** этими типами.  А для более краткой записи был придуман синтаксический сахар в виде замены **Nullable** на знак вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Это типы, которые [допускают null](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/2cf62fcy.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

> Тип называется допускающим значение
> NULL, если ему может быть присвоено
> как непустое значение, так и значение
> null, означающее, что значение у типа
> отсутствует. По умолчанию все
> ссылочные типы, например String,
> допускают значение NULL, но все
> типы-значения, например Int32, его не
> допускают.
>
> В C# и Visual Basic, вы можете
> пометить тип значения как допускающий
> NULL, если добавите символ ? после
> имени типа.

[Типы, допускающие значения NULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)

[Nullable<T> - структура](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b3h38hb0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)