# Зачем здесь используется знак «?»

Tags: c#

```
public static int? Multiply(string arguments) => 0;
```

Зачем в данном фрагменте кода используется, и именно `int?` используется оператор `?`?

Comment: зачем вообще нужна функция, которая всегда возвращает 0?

Comment: @tym32167, чтобы был константный `0` очевидно :)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Int? или bool?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/367575/int-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-bool)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это [nullable structs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=netcore-3.1). На самом деле это синтаксический сахар, и `int?` тоже самое, что и `System.Nullable<int>`.

Зачем нужны эти nullable structs? Дело в том, что структуры сами по себе не могут быть `null`, то иногда бывает довольно полезным пометить поле/переменную, ссылающееся/-уюся на структуру как `null`. Для этого и создан тип `Nullable<T>`.

Вот члены этого типа:

- `HasValue` – если помечено как «не `null`», возвращает `true`, иначе `false`
- `Value` –  если помечено как «не `null`», возвращает значение структуры, иначе выбрасывает исключение
- `GetValueOrDefault(T defaultValue)` – тоже что и `Value`, только вместо исключения возвращает значение по умолчанию, указанное в аргументе `defaultValue`

---

Несколько рекомендаций по использованию nullable structs. Лучше писать так:

```
bool TryDo(out int value);
```

...а не так:

```
int? Do();
```

Почему? Вот пример:

```
if (TryDo(out var val)) // int
{
    // "then" block
}
else
{
    // "else" block
}
```

Если использовать 2-й вариант, то это будет выглядеть так:

```
var val = Do(); // int?

if (val.HasValue) // or `!(val is null)`
{
    // "then" block

    // ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ:
    // При этом обращение идёт не к переменной `val`, а к
    // св-ву `Value`. Это ухудшает читаемость. Либо используем
    // неудобное св-во, либо кешируем значение в виде
    // `var valVal = val.Value`, но это же смешно
}
else
{
    // "else" block
}
```

Nullable structs следует использовать для хранения и для передачи как аргумент метода (`in`/`ref`/`out`/без модификаторов), тип generic'а.

Я настоятельно не рекомендую использовать nullable structs как тип возвращаемого значения (опять же, кроме геттеров св-в, или методов, возвращающих данные).

Comment: _При этом обращение идёт не к переменной `val`, а к св-ву `Value`. Это ухудшает читаемость. Либо используем неудобное свойство, либо кешируем значение в виде `var valVal = val.Value`, но это же смешно_ а добавь пример, где такое нужно? То есть где не будет работать именно использование `val`?

Comment: ну и вместо `TryDo(out var val)` можно точно так же делать `Do() is int val`

Comment: @Grundy а в каких примерах это работать не будет? я же написал, что не работает в таких случаях: `bool Try(out int? arg)`.

Comment: @Grundy про `Do() is var val` не знал, спс (чтобы не удаляло)

Comment: У тебя же примечание написано что что-то ухудшает читаемость, но примера, где без этого ухудшения не обойтись - нет. То есть ты можешь использовать `val.Value`, но почему просто `val` не использовать?